# Pgadmin3 not working on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, postgresql, rails, ruby-on-rails

I installed `postgres` than `pgadmin3` on Ubuntu 15.10. install was successful but when I type `pgadmin3` in terminal and hit enter I get this following error :

```
Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected. The library used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1009,wx containers,compatible with 2.6), and your program used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6). Aborted (core dumped)
```

I googled a lot but couldn't find solution, one solution i read was related to codeblocks and the person was getting the same error as me but other guy told the solution that you have to downgrade your Ubuntu to 14.04. I don't know whats wrong with it kindly help me.

Comment: Have you get any solution for it ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Are you installing the package via the official postgres repos by any chance? If so make sure your Ubuntu Codename is set properly in the apt file to match the repository to use.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:        15.10
Codename:       wily

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list 
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wily-pgdg main
```

Mine was set to **precise-pgdg** in the apt file instead of **wily-pgdg**.

If I am correct this problem arises because of a library needed should be compiled using the same compiler used for PgAdmin. As the version of the compiler used differs for **precise** and **wily** the packages are not interchangeable in the case of PgAdmin.